# Freezing a JSP Page

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, jakarta-ee

I have a jsp page which when submitted takes somewhere around 5 mins to go to the next page process and come  back if there are several items to be submitted.

During that time the status bar shows a loading status until it can move to the submitted page.

In the mean time the user is free to click any buttons he likes.

I would like to freeze the jsp page during this time so that the user will not be able to click any butoons during this interval.

How can I achieve the same.

```
A small snippet:
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function submit page()
{
document.forms["submitForm"].submit();
}
</script>
<body>
<form name="submitForm" action"newPage.jsp" method="post">
<input type="button" onclick="page()"/>
</form>
```

The iframe iin which all the jsp's are displayed is as shown:

```
<iframe id="Content" name="Content" style="width:100%; height:100%; border:0; background: #green;" scrolling="yes" src="Start.jsp"></iframe>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use .blockUI() plug in jQuery

It is a nice plugin to do that

```
function submit page()
{
            $.blockUI({

                    css: {
                        top: 0,
                        left: 0,
                        width: '100%'
                    }
                });
document.forms["submitForm"].submit();
}


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
```

[see here](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/) for details

Comment: @Dark Matter did you checked it

Comment: Of course, this doesn't stop the user from using the browsers back button. Good plugin though.

Comment: the requirement is user will not be able to click any butoons during this interval.So it will fulfill the requirement

Comment: the issue here is its an actual submit and not an ajax call.How will this suit my case.

Comment: you can call a function in onsubmit by using blockui.Whenever you redirected to other page it will automatically closed

Comment: I have added a small snippet can you point me to where i need to add the call to blockui

Comment: did you added any jQuery files

Comment: try to import the files what i suggested

Comment: Yes it worked.But I have a new issue.My jsp page is being displayed in an iframe and the blocking is covered to that iframe size , how can I make the blocking screen to appaear in full screen.

Comment: Yes this code works but it is only getting displayed in the small iframe how can I extend i to the whole window.

Comment: are u submitting the only i frame content or entirer page content.I dont have that much knowledge what iframe is

Comment: I'm submitting only the jsp content. Iframe does not change at all.Is sort of like a template in which all the jsp's gets displayed.

Comment: where is your javascript .In iframe or jsp?

Comment: My java script in in jsp page.BTW i have added the iframe in which the jsp's are added to the question.

Comment: in the link i provided you can see both examples for entire page and and foe a block .Did you see that

Comment: I can access the iframe by the foll code `parent.parent.document.getElementById('Content')` where content is the id of the iframe any way I can use this in blocking code. Yes I saw the freeze for a block but it cant be applied to iframe.

Comment: It blocks but the iframe section is not blocked .Its like the middle portion of the page blocked and the rest at corners in unblocked.

Comment: @Dark Matter sorry i dont have that much of knowledge on iframe.So i am unable to help

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.Finally solved it.I just blocked the page with white colour and it dosent't seem odd.